# Virtualbox Games / EXE Runs at 640x480

Tags: virtualbox

I am using windows 10 as a host machine and i can't get my games to run on it.

That's why i have installed virtualbox with a windows 7 virtual machine.

It all works except when i start the game it runs in 640x480! (Virtualbox itself runs in 1920x1080)!

I have installed quest editions and everything but i can't figure it out.

If you can help me, i will really appreciate it.

This is what i have tried:

- change the screen resolution
- install virtualbox quest edition
- Tried to force a resolution (couldn't find out how)

And yes i have tried everything on the host machine to make the game work (compatibility mode, and more) windows 10 just doesn't like the games.

2nd question
(I have also copied 2 other games from program files on the host to the virtual machine but they don't work also. Do i have to install the game normally? i am asuming so)

Comment: What games are you trying to run? Why won't they run on Windows 10? Did you enable acceleration for the VM?

Comment: Is it located at settings -> System -> Acceleration? wich options do i have to run?

And i am playing games from the year 2000 in about that area used to work on win7

Comment: Not, the options I'm talking about are found on the Display tab. It could be rather important and by actually spelling out what you mean by you "can't get them to run" you might be able to avoid a VM altogether. In addition are you not able to change the resolution within the game? Using a VM for gaming is usually not the best idea.